# Default Image Gallery not opening in android HoneyComb tablet (v 3.2) programatically

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, image-gallery

I am using this code, to open the default Image gallery and select one Image.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse
                ("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));


    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

This works perfectly fine in android 2.2 and 2.3, but doesn't work in HoneyComb tablet (v 3.2).

What could be the issue ?

Comment: can you elaborate on what "doesn't work" means?

Comment: The image Gallery doesn't open up,and the activity is resumed to from where it started.

Comment: you may want to close the question then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 2);
```